# Count of occurrences while including other information

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, I have a list of dictionaries. I want to count occurrences of each name, but I also want to merge the other data with it.

Here is the input

```
task_list = [
    {
        "name": "user1",
        "email": "user1@gmail.com",
        "task": "12121"
    },
    {
        "name": "user2",
        "email": "user2@gmail.com",
        "task": "13131"
    },
    {
        "name": "user1",
        "email": "user1@gmail.com",
        "task": "14141"
    }
]
```

Expected output

```
[
    {
        "name": "user1",
        "email": "user1@gmail.com",
        "task": ["12121", "14141"],
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "user2",
        "email": "user2@gmail.com",
        "task": ["13131"],
        "count": 1
    }
]
```

I currently only get the count for each user but I am lost on how I can merge other information with the count.

Here is my code

```
counts = {}
for task in task_list:
    if task["name"] not in counts.keys():
        counts[task["name"]] = 1
    else:
        counts[task["name"]] +=1
```

Here is the current output I am getting so far

```
[
    {
        "name": "user1",
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "user2",
        "count": 1
    }
]
```

All I can think of is looping 5-6 times and generate the expected output. But I think that is a bad solution. Are there any packages or some other solution to accomplish this?

Comment: whats your code?

Comment: You just need to `reduce` the list...

Comment: edited and added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html) can do the job

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(task_list)

# Groupby similar keys and get len of task
df.groupby(['name', 'email']).agg({'task': list}).assign(count=lambda x: x['task'].map(lambda x: len(x))).reset_index().to_dict(orient='records')
```

```
[{'name': 'user1', 'email': 'user1@gmail.com', 'task': ['12121', '14141'], 'count': 2}, {'name': 'user2', 'email': 'user2@gmail.com', 'task': ['13131'], 'count': 1}]
```

Comment: Not sure if OP has exposure to Pandas. We may have to provide him a normal dict / list solution.

Comment: do you need more help here? If not can you accept an answer so this question can be closed

Answer (score 1):

This code has done it for me:

```
i = 0
for d1 in task_list:
    i += 1
    for d2 in task_list[i:]:
        if d1["name"] == d2["name"]:
            if isinstance(d1["task"], list):
                d1["task"] =  d1["task"] + [d2["task"]]
                task_list.remove(d2)
            else:
                d1["task"] = [d1["task"], d2["task"]]
                task_list.remove(d2)
```